# How to define label text vs body text?

Tags: typography, style-guide, content-strategy, design-system

I am setting up the initial typography style guide for a mobile fintech application, the issue I am stuck with is how to communicate what part of content needs to use "label" style vs "body" style.

**My approach**

Differentiate by the quantity of text for say,

- If the content is just 2-3 words then its a "label"
- Else I call it "body"

Though somehow I feel such differentiation is very counterintuitive to the general usage and definition of terms "Label" and "Body".

Looking for some suggestions around this issue.
Thanks in advance, Cheers!

Comment: Labels can be many things, you need to differentiate by context, not content length. Also you might need a content strategy guide.

Comment: There's your answer right there. Think about how data is represented in context (label / value pairs is one example in forms). @jazZRo summed it up. You can also look up design systems like Material or Lightning (Salesforce design system) and start from there.